# setState doesn't work with DraggableScrollable don't work

Tags: flutter

I have a DraggableScrollableSheet in which I have two buttons Yes and No. If the user clicked on yes then the spinner is shown and if the function sendEmail returns true then a new DraggableScrollableSheet will be shown.

My problem is when I do a setState for the variable isLoading while clicking on Yes the DraggableScrollableSheet is closed then if the email is send DraggableScrollableSheet will be shown. I don't know why the first one is closed. When I removed the set State the spinner is not shown at all!

```
                        InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            print(isLoading);
                            // setState(() {
                            //isLoading = true;
                            //});
                            sendEmail(widget.measure).then((sendEmail) {
                              if (sendEmail == true) {
                                // setState(() {
                                //   isLoading = false;
                                //  });
                                print(isLoading);
                                newTransmissionController.reset();
                                transmissionDoneController.animateTo(
                                  0.95,
                                  duration:
                                      const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
                                  curve: Curves.easeOutBack,
                                );
                              } else {

                                // setState(() {
                                isLoading = false;
                                //  });
                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                Navigator.of(context).push(PageRouteBuilder(
                                    pageBuilder: (context, animation1,
                                            animation2) =>
                                        const TransmissionErrorPage()));
                              }
                            });
                          },
                          child: AnimatedContainer(
                              duration:
                                  const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                              height:
                                  MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                      0.08,
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  horizontal: 5),
                              width:
                                  MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                      0.18,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: const Color(0xFF008DFF),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              ),
                              child: Center(
                                child: !isLoading
                                    ? const Text(
                                        "Yes",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          fontSize: 17,
                                          fontFamily: 'SFProRegular',
                                        ),
                                      )
                                    : const Center(
                                        child:
                                            CircularProgressIndicator(
                                          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                          valueColor:
                                              AlwaysStoppedAnimation<
                                                      Color>(
                                                  Color(0xFF008DFF)),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                              )),
                        ),
```

newTransmissionController and transmissionDoneController  are  DraggableScrollableController.

```
 DraggableScrollableController newTransmissionController =
      DraggableScrollableController();
  DraggableScrollableController transmissionDoneController =
      DraggableScrollableController();
```

Comment: Are you using `DraggableScrollableSheet` inside `showModalBottomSheet`?

Comment: no DraggableScrollableSheet is not useed inside showModalBottomSheet

Comment: Can you include full snippet that will reproduce the error

Answer (score 0):

Wrap `DraggableScrollableSheet` with `StatefulBuilder` and use its setstate to update the bottomSheet UI.

```dart
showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    builder: (c) {
      return StatefulBuilder(
        builder: (context, setStateSB) => DraggableScrollableSheet(
          builder: (context, scrollController) {

            /// use `setStateSB` to update inside dialog
            /// use `setState` to update state class UI
          },
        ),
      );
    });
```

Comment: This worked for me, thank you @Md. Yeasin Sheikh